# inotify::Notifier timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inotify

I'm using rb-notify to monitor a directory within my Rspec tests for a Rails project. If the file isn't found then the inotify continues in an endless loop. Is there a way to tell it to give up after 10 seconds.

```
@notifier = INotify::Notifier.new
@notifier.watch(DownloadHelpers::PATH.to_s, :create) do |file|
  puts "Check: #{file.name}"

  if file.name.eql?(File.basename(@filename.to_s))
    @pdf = PdfReader.new(@filename)

    # Check PDF
    expect(@pdf.page_count).to eq(1)
    expect(@pdf.pages[1]).to have_text("CONTRACTORS")

    @notifier.stop # Stops the infinite loop watch
  end
end

visit "/#/contractors_report"
within "#heading" do
  expect(page).to have_text("Contractors")
end

click_on("pdf-btn")

@notifier.run # Make sure we finish our thread
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [advanced usage](https://github.com/guard/rb-inotify#advanced-usage) section on inotify's readme on GitHub:

```rb
 # Wait 10 seconds for an event then give up
 if IO.select([notifier.to_io], [], [], 10)
   notifier.process
 end
```